# Display post content from wp_nav_menu?

Tags: wordpress

I have made a wp menu that lists a bunch of posts.
I am able to list these posts' titles but not its content.

wp_nav_menu(array( 'menu' => 'Compatibility Matrix') );

How do i display the contents of each item (post title) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't list the post's content with the wp_nav_menu function, that is solely used to create a navigation menu with the post/page titles or custom title that you assign the menu item.

You need to use a loop to display the content.  This is a very basic loop:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can modify it to suit your needs.  Here are a couple resources to help you out:

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/a-beginners-guide-to-the-wordpress-loop/